# CSS Problems with Flask Web App

Tags: python, css, flask

I can't get the CSS to output correctly - my webpages are all unstyled.

This is my link in all my templates. What am I doing wrong?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/>
```

Is there anything special that I have to do with Flask to get it to work?

I've been trying and changing things for about half an hour but can't seem to get it right.

To sum it up: How do you do CSS with Flask - do I have to have any special python code?

Comment: Check your FireBug or Inspector, are you getting a 404 not found on that file? Make sure the path's correct.

Comment: Hmm as long as it still goes between the <head> tags it should be ok. Is it possible to see the site you're working on.

Comment: Or how about setting an absolute path, I prefer not to use them.

Comment: Apparently Flask needs stylesheets to be specifically in a static folder - I originally thought it was optional and the site used static as an example, but I guess not.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special with Flask to get CSS to work. Maybe you're putting `style.css` in `flask_project/stylesheets/`? Unless properly configured, such directories won't be served by your application. Check out the [Static Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files) section of the [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) for some more information on this. But, in summary, this is what you'd want to do:

1. Move static files you need to `project_root/static/`. Let's assume that you moved `stylesheets/style.css` into `project_root/static/stylesheets/style.css`.
2. Change

   ```
   <link ... href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" />
   ```

   This tells the template parser (Jinja2) to tell Flask to find the configured static directory in your project directory (by default, `static/`) and return the path of the file.

   - If you *really* wanted to, you could just set the path as `/static/stylesheets/style.css`. But you really shouldn't do that - using `url_for` allows you to switch your static directory and still have things work, among other advantages.

And, as @RachelSanders said in her answer:

> In a production setting, you'd ideally serve your static files via apache or nginx, but this is good enough for dev.

Answer (score 77):

Try reloading the browser using:

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Comment: WHAT KIND OF MAGIC IS THIS??

Comment: Bypassing the cache. This got me as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Comment: It is called reloading the web cleaning caché.

Answer (score 23):

**4 steps to do this** (building a lot on some of the other answers here, presuming you've got Flask all set up properly):

1) Create a static folder in your `app` folder:`[root_folder]/app/static/`

2) Move all of your static content (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) into those folders. Keep the content in their respective folders (not mandatory, just neater and more organized).

3) Modify your `__init__.py` file in the `app` folder to have this line:

```
app.static_folder = 'static'
```

This will allow your app to identify your `static` folder and read it accordingly.

4) In your HTML, set up your file links as such:

```
<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='[css_folder]/[css-file].css') }}" />
```

For example, if you call your CSS folder 'stylesheets' and file 'styles':

```
<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/styles.css') }}" />
```

That should set everything up properly. Good luck!

Comment: Can this be done with template inheritance? I'm trying to use this code within my base.html, which other html files inherit from, but no luck. No error, just not working..

Answer (score 10):

You need to create a folder called "static" inside your Flask app, and then put all your CSS files there.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files

In a production setting, you'd ideally serve your static files via apache or nginx, but this is good enough for dev.

Answer (score 3):

In my case - safari on macOS 10.13 - clearing the cache did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

ctrl + shift + R trick works, especially if css loaded during the 1st run (that means, all paths are fine); but, not able to reload if changes made to css.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do a hard refresh in the browser. You might be looking at a cached version. 
Hold down CTRL and press F5 in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I had created static folder put my CSS in it and had properly linked it, but it wasn't working. I cleared browser's cache and it worked. Alternatively you can hard refresh the browser by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on chrome.

Comment: Does that fully address it though?

Comment: Yeah it doesnt but i thought this might help someone.I mean who has linked the files and all but is not getting the output. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply hard refresh using (mac OS):

```
command + shift + R
```

Answer (score 1):

"If you change a static file, refresh the browser page. If
the change doesn’t show up, try clearing your browser’s cache." -Flask documentation

Comment: You could have put this as a comment

Answer (score 1):

init issue
After remove the static folder parameter, my css can load not problem.

***Before***
app = Flask(**name**, static_folder="/mypath")

***After***
app = Flask(**name**)

And remember to use : <link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='yourFolder/style.css') }}" />

Answer (score 0):

The order of handler might cause the problems:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application

will work instead of

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Create the static path whenever you want it inside your project. In my case I placed it in /root_folder/frontend/static for the static files and /root_folder/frontend/templates for my templates, then I passed the routes to the constructor, like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../frontend/templates', 
static_folder='../frontend/static/')
```

Finally my html tag looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css">
```