# css grid not showing on chrome - 200 error

Tags: html, css, flask

I cannot display my css grid properly in the different browsers.

I get this error in Terminal
"GET /static/stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

[Firefox on the left, Chrome on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGJb6.png)

In Firefox on the left, everything works fine!

Chrome on the right is not displaying any css.

Any idea whats' is going on?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" />
    <title>This is the title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item item5">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background: white;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.item{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.item:nth-child(even){
    background: orange;
}
```

routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)  
from app import routes
```

Comment: your screenshot does not match your html, where are '250px', 'lorem ipsum' green texts?

Comment: okay, I updated the picture. I had edited my code to make it more readable. This is exactly the code and the images im looking at now

Comment: I don't see .boxed in css, but it is referenced in HTML

Comment: I took them off to see if the error was still showing and it was. you can see it in the css now .

Comment: It looks like chrome cannot read my CSS. maybe he is not picking up on my css link.

Comment: I didn't realize but I get this error in Terminal:
"GET /static/stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: 200 is success status code, how it could be an error, please attach screenshot

Comment: try clearing your cache (CTRL + Shift + R), or rename your css file in source code and filesystem
also this issue looks similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772884/css-problems-with-flask-web-app

Comment: oh I didn't realize lol. Okay

Comment: Yes, I have them in: projectRoot/static/stylesheets/style.css

Comment: CTRL+F5 perhaps both browsers are showing correctly, but FF is still loading some file **from cache**?.. that actually does not exist any more for chrome? (or vice-versa)

Comment: append some number to file name in order to invalidate cache and don't forget to change it in html, something like style111.css

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo you mean `style.css?t=123` (which is simpler and quite enough)

Comment: wow, it worked! I appended style11.css and I also pushed ctrl+f5 and somehow chrome picked it up! Thank you guys so much :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah, forgot, in this case you don't need to change filename

Comment: @AlexFortin good job

Comment: @AlexFortin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671168/why-adding-version-number-to-css-file-path for more info

Comment: Okay thank you, I will be keeping this in mind

Comment: If I add the ?v=5 chrome and Firefox cannot see the css anymore
style11.css?v=5

Comment: @AlexFortin hm, strange... It's a classic, to add a query-param with a timestamp to force a refetch