# Local Flask - HTML Project Link to CSS and JS not Linking when run

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, cs50

I have started to work on my final project for CS50 by creating a web application.  I started making all of the basic layouts to my html/css/javascript files on my local system, and installed flask locally to try it out.  Although when I directly open the html files, it is linked up to the css and jaascript files, when I run it in flask, it gives me the error of "404 not found" for all of the css and javascript files I am trying to apply to the html.

Here is the code in my html file:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/page_layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/navbars.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/styles.css">
```

The html files are in the templates folder, and I have a separate adjacent folder called "styles" for the css files and "javascript" for the js file.  I tried every kind of formatting to this and cannot get it to work.  Does anyone know why this might be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the appropriate syntax to get my web application to function as I wanted.

The answer I found here:
[CSS Problems with Flask Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772884/css-problems-with-flask-web-app)

I used the syntax provided and am not running into any issues anymore.